# Deriving an expression of kinetic energy

Tags: classical-mechanics

How is it that

$$
mv\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}mv^2\right)
$$

I cannot seem to arrive at the expression, getting stuck at 
$$
\frac{d(mv^2)}{dt}=\frac{dm}{dt}v^2+2mv\frac{dv}{dt}
$$

Comment: m is constant in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Because $v$ is a function of $t$, you have: $$\frac{d}{dt}v^{2} = 2v \frac{dv}{dt}$$ and thus:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2}mv^{2} = mv \frac{dv}{dt}.$$

**Note:** Your first expression is true when the mass does not depend on time.